# Problems saving title/description with cakephp2.0 file upload plug in

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, image-uploading

I am using http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#configuration to upload images. I got it to work fine (in terms of uploading images) but I can't get it to save title/description in my db.

so I have Image.php model that has the following code

```
<?php
class Image extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Image';

    public $actsAs = array('Uploader.Attachment', 'Uploader.FileValidation');
    public $validate = array(
                            'title' => array( 'rule' => 'notEmpty')
                            );  

}
```

In my view I have bunch of fields such as

```
echo $this->Form->input('title');
```

My ImagesController.php add function looks like this

```
 function add($number_of_images = 1){ 

        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            var_export($this->data);
            exit();
            $count = 1;
            foreach($this->data['Images'] as $entry){
                $file_name = "file" . $count;
                if ($data_s = $this->Uploader->upload($file_name)) {
                    $this->Image->saveAll($data_s);
                }
                $count++;
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash("Your image(s) has been saved");
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));

        }else{   
            // make sure 10 is max amount of images a user can upload
            if($number_of_images <= 10 ){
                $this->set('number_of_images', $number_of_images);
            }else{
                // set to default 1
                $this->set('number_of_images', '1');
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click save, the image gets uploaded but title/description doesnt get uploaded or validated. This is how my var_export($this->data) looks like

```
array ( 'selectImages' => '1', 'Images' => array ( 'title' => 'adsafdas', 'description' => 'asdfasd', 'tags' => '', 'file1' => array ( 'name' => '308462_926071922398_11704522_41424436_637322498_n.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg', 'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php7tycbu', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 81638, ), ), )
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According with the link, `$this->Uploader->upload()` returns only data of file uploaded. So, you need merge this array with the other fields of your form `$this->data` before `saveAll`.

However, if you need validate form data before upload the file, use `$this->Image->validates($this->request->data)`.

Comment: @CodeCrack can you update your question with scheme of these two tables and your form?

Comment: How would I merge it since it's already merged when controller calls $this->request->data and looks like this


if I var_export($data_s); while uploading 2 images, it looks like this...

array ( 'selectImages' => '2', 'Images' => array ( 'title' => 'Alex', 'description' => 'Test', 'tags' => 'test', 'file1' => array ( 'name' => '328464_10150322152163622_584788621_8019260_905395239_o.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg', 'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpbPMHEM', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 369085, ), 'file2' => array ( 'name' => '', 'type' => '', 'tmp_name' => '', 'error' => 4, 'size' => 0, ), ), )